# How to overwrite a portion of a binary file using C++?

Tags: c++, file, binary, fstream, overwrite

I have a binary file, and let's say at byte 11 to byte 14, representing an integer = 100.
Now I want to replace that integer value  = 200 instead of the existing one.

How can I do that using C++?
Thanks
T.

Comment: What have you tried and why did it fail?

Comment: I don't know how to move to a specific location of the binary file. Also, I am not sure if I use the command f.write() it would overwrite the existing content, or append to that location.

Comment: Look for `fseek` in the same place you learned about `write`. If you seek to a certain position and call `write` the output will go to the current location that you moved to.

Comment: Have you looked in [the manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend. Searching for "C++ binary files" will give you some useful pages, such as: [This useful link](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs380/HANDOUTS/cppBinaryFileIO-2.html)

In short, you can do something like this:

```
int main() 
{ 
  int x; 
  streampos pos; 
  ifstream infile; 
  infile.open("silly.dat", ios::binary | ios::in); 
  infile.seekp(243, ios::beg); // move 243 bytes into the file 
  infile.read(&x, sizeof(x)); 
  pos = infile.tellg(); 
  cout << "The file pointer is now at location " << pos << endl; 
  infile.seekp(0,ios::end); // seek to the end of the file 
  infile.seekp(-10, ios::cur); // back up 10 bytes 
  infile.close(); 
}
```

That works for reading. To open a file for output:

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("junk.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
```

Combining those two and adjusting for your specific needs shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

The process is a bit trickier. Let me put down steps needed with help of code snippet and comments:

```
  // Open a file to write. Use both ios::out and ios::in. If you dont 
  // use ios::in then file will get truncated.
  fstream outputfile("data.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | ios::in );
  if(outputfile.is_open())
  {
    int value{200}; //value to be written
    outputfile.seekp(10); //As we desired to overwrite from 11th byte
    outputfile.write((char*)(&value), sizeof(int)); //4 bytes will be replaced
    outputfile.close();
  }
```

**Note:**Please make sure not to use `std::ios::app` mode while opening file otherwise all write operation will end up in getting added to end of the file(at the tail).